# JsounUtils.fromJson -first letter is capital letter and JsonUtils will not map field with capital letter

Tags: json, convertto-json

I want to parse:

```
List<Resource> resources =
        Arrays.asList(JsonUtils.fromJson(json, new TypeReference<Resource[]>() {}));
```

and in `json` one field begins with capital letter:
`WebUrl` instead of `webUrl` therefore this field is NULL.

How can I force `JsonUtils` to map fields with first capital letter too? Of coure in my object I have `WebUrl` field (with first capital letter)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I need to add `@JsonProperty("WebUrl")`

like

```
@JsonProperty("WebUrl")
private String webUrl
```